# How to get all user profile in sharepoint using REST API

Tags: office-365, rest, user-profile

I am trying to get list of all user profiles using RestAPI in office 365, But could not find any method for it.

I can get property of any specific user successfully by following method:

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Name')?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'"
```

But I want to get list of all user. Is it any method available using REST API?

Answer (score 2):

## Still this no API for retrieving all user profiles

You can get current user's profile

```
_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

Or a particular user's profile by login name

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|xx@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'
```

**BUT** You can get available user profiles in a site

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList
```

Comment: When I try to get UserInformationList using rest api, I get {"location":null} as a result

Comment: did you mean `loaction` is a managed property?

Comment: No, all I get this response only. I was expecting list of users

Comment: can re-check every thing? It is not expected

Answer (score 0):

This is the endpoint that serves a list of all users in a site:

```
/_api/Web/SiteUsers
```

Here is the UserCollection resource reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_UserCollection

Here is the overall REST API endpoints' reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx

Comment: `/_api/Web/SiteUsers` will return only available users in site! not all users

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. As much as I understood, siteusers and user profiles are different thing